# How to format Zip -code (XXXXX-XXXX) for country USA?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is a requirement to display a formatted US Zip code on screen from a oracle view given below, the zip code should be formatted XXXXX-XXXX only if country code is US and length of zip-code is 9-digits.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PARTY_ADDR
AS 
SELECT ZIP_CODE AS ZIP_POSTAL_CODE,COUNTRY_CD,ADDRESS_LINE_1  
FROM PARTY
```

Comment: Best practice is to handle display requirements at the application layer.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://community.oracle.com/thread/830832?start=0&tstart=0 or http://share-examples.blogspot.com/2011/07/oracle-sql-formatting-zip-code.html  Show some effort... What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I will assume that the field is varchar as many country postal codes are a mix of numbers and letters.

So if you are insisting on doing this in your query, something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN country_code = 'US' and length(postal_code) = 9
       THEN substr(postal_code,1,5)||'-'||substr(postal_Code(6,4)
       else postal_Code
       end as disply_postal_Code
from your_Table
```

Comment: This is clearly not written for SSMS. 
Here is SSMS code:
case when len(si.Zip) = 9 then substring(si.Zip,1,5) + '-' + substring(si.Zip,6,4) else si.Zip end

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I use and it works great every time.

```
'ZipCode'       = case LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(zipcode)))
                            when 9 then
                            STUFF(zipcode, 6, 0, '-') 
                            else zipcode
                            end
```

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_REPLACE( ) to the rescue! Of course add your other WHERE clause criteria of country code, etc.

```
SQL> with tbl(zip) as (
     select '12345' from dual union
     select '12345-1234' from dual
   )
   select REGEXP_REPLACE(ZIP,'(\d{5})(\d{4})','\1-\2') ZIP
   from tbl;

ZIP
------------------------------------------------------------
12345
12345-1234

SQL>
```

Note that there is a possible caveat that should be mentioned.  This works because if the length is 9 digits, it gets broken into 2 sets, one of 5 and one of 4 and displayed with a dash in between.  Anything else and the regex is not matched so the original string is returned, including bad data. Add some more test data to the WITH clause as well as doing some sanity checks on your data first to see if you have any bad data that needs to be cleaned.  Good thing to do anyway I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

> Just an alternative. Instead of REGEXP we can also use OLDSCHOOL
>   methods :P like SUBSTR as we have to only format US based zips. As you
>   have provided that zip for US will be 9 digits only so based on that
>   this code will help you too.

```
WITH tbl AS
  ( SELECT '12345' ZIP,'IN' country FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT '123451234' ZIP, 'US' country FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT '123456' zip,'KR' country FROM dual
  )
SELECT DECODE(TBL.country,'US',SUBSTR(tbl.zip,1,5)
  ||'-'
  ||SUBSTR(tbl.zip,6,LENGTH(tbl.zip)),TBL.ZIP) zip_formatted
FROM tbl ;

--------------------------------OUTPUT---------------------------------------------

DECODE(TBL
----------
12345
12345-1234
123456

Elapsed: 00:00:06.17
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```